# 64 bit assembly failing to load

Tags: c#, .net, clr

1. There’s machine A with VS2012 installed on it, there’s a small VC++.NET project, we build this project in 64bit configuration, it generates a DLL (say TestDLL.dll).
2. On the same machine A, if I create a small console application and write
   ***`var objBroker = new CUccxBroker();`***, it works fine, "`CUccxBroker`" is a part of "`TextDLL.dll`'.
3. But if I copy the DLL generated on machine A, and paste it on machine B, write the same code it fails with the error "`Couldn't load file or assembly TestDLL.dll, file or one of its dependencies not found`"

VS version on both the machines are same, not sure what starts working after I compile the code on the machine and then use the DLL. Any help will be great.

Comment: It sounds like your TestDLL.dll has an external reference/dependency that machine A has but machine B doesn't.  Check the references of your VC++ project.  If I recall correctly, VC++ projects can be static bound or dynamic bound.  Static means all required reference code is included in library/executable.  Dynamic means it expects the references (MS C++ library maybe?) to be available.

Comment: Hello @Mmm, Thanks for your help, I forgot to add that , if I build the project on machine B it starts working. where in VS should I chk for references, sorry I've no C++ experience..

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you have a different version of a required C++ library on machine B than you do A.  Look for project properties somewhere ... there ought to be an option for linking with static libraries as opposed to dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of the 'dependency walker' utility (freeware available on web).  This will display graphically a tree showing the assembly's dependencies, those assembly's dependencies (not circular), etc. It highlights which dependencies are missing, making it easy to find what is missing.